# How to revoke auth token in spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2

In logout controller I tryed to write a lot of combination of code. Now I have this:

```
final Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

if (auth != null) {
    new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
}

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
auth.setAuthenticated(false);
```

But after provided code execution token still valid.

What do I wrong? How to revoke token eventually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The class you're looking for is
[`DefaultServices`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.html), method `revokeToken(String tokenValue)`.

[Here](https://github.com/raonicoelho/silverauth/blob/master/src/main/java/com/silverauth/controller/TokenController.java) an exemple of a controller that revokes token, and [here](https://github.com/raonicoelho/silverauth/blob/master/src/main/java/com/silverauth/config/OAuth2Config.java) the oauth2 configuration with the `DefaultServices` bean.

Comment: @raonirenosto, I've run into problems with autowiring a class with Spring been proxy using your example. I had to change DefaultTokenServices to ConsumerTokenServices (which is an interface) for it to work.  But thanks for suggesting using DefaultTokenServices.revokeToken().

Comment: Since I last saw, Spring Oauth has changed many classes. I guess the framework is more stable now than the time I wrote this example.

Comment: Both links do not exist anymore :(

Comment: It seems that following links could be used as a replacement:

TokenController: https://github.com/kiquetal/silverauth/blob/master/src/main/java/com/silverauth/controller/TokenController.java

OAuth2Config: https://github.com/kiquetal/silverauth/blob/master/src/main/java/com/silverauth/config/OAuth2Config.java

It seems to be same repository on another account.

Answer (score 9):

If you need to revoke a token for another user than the current one (E.g. an admin wants to disable a user account), you can use this:

```
Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> tokens = tokenStore.findTokensByClientIdAndUserName(
                                                           "my_oauth_client_id", 
                                                           user.getUsername());
for (OAuth2AccessToken token : tokens) {
  consumerTokenServices.revokeToken(token.getValue());
}
```

With `tokenStore` being an `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore` and `consumerTokenServices` being a `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.ConsumerTokenServices`

Comment: when doing this its showing "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method revokeToken(String) from the type ConsumerTokenServices".

Comment: Mohammed Shafeek, you must be calling the method revokeToken using the classname instead of using the name of the object instantiated from the class ConsumerTokenServices

Answer (score 0):

the thread is a bit old but for JWTToken users this is not working as the tokens are not stored. 
So another option is to use a filter. 
1 create a method for admin to lock/unlock a user on your database.
2 use a filter and if the method needs authentication check if the user is active or not

exemple :

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if(authentication != null
            &&  authentication.getName() != null
            && !authentication.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("anonymousUser")) {
        UserModel user = userService.getUser(authentication.getName());
        if(user != null && !user.isActivated())
            throw new SecurityException("SECURITY_USER_DISABLED");
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

On client side just intercept this error and disconnect user
hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example of token revocation for current authorized user using [DefaultTokenServices](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.html):

1. Need Bean for Default token store

   ```
   @Bean 
   public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
   }
   ```
2. Then you can write your own controller

   ```
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("/user")
   public class UserApi {

   @Autowired
   private DefaultTokenServices tokenServices;

   @Autowired
   private TokenStore tokenStore;

   @DeleteMapping("/logout")
   @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
   public void revokeToken() {
       final OAuth2Authentication auth = (OAuth2Authentication) SecurityContextHolder
               .getContext().getAuthentication();
       final String token = tokenStore.getAccessToken(auth).getValue();
       tokenServices.revokeToken(token);
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Answer (score -3):

Autowire the DefaultTokenServices then use this code:

```
String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
String tokenValue = authHeader.replace("bearer", "").trim();
tokenService.revokeToken(tokenValue);
tokenService.setAccessTokenValiditySeconds(1);
tokenService.setRefreshTokenValiditySeconds(1);
```

Just try the code to revoke the access token.

Comment: Someone should kindly explain why this answer was downvoted. Why is this not advisable?

Comment: @Olantobi Because changing the token validity time this way changes the token validity for the whole application, not just one token.