# Spring Security: How to find refresh token using access token at logout

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

At user logout, I would like to revoke refresh token too. Problem is that I cannot find it in `LogoutHandler`. I only have access token. Also `Authentication` object is null.

Configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .....
        .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
                .addLogoutHandler(customLogoutHandler)
                .deleteCookies("rememberMe")
                .logoutSuccessUrl(loginPage)
        .....
        ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do global search for @Component("customLogoutHandler"), @Service("customLogoutHandler"), "customLogoutHandler" etc.. in your project.

I have similar setup with logout success handler in Configuration file that looks like this:

```
@Autowired
private LogoutSuccessHandler myLogoutSuccessHandler;
```

Then the custom handler, mind you revoking the refresh token will depend on what type of TokenStore you are using, JDBC, InMemory etc:

```
@Component("myLogoutSuccessHandler")
public class MyLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //logic to revoke tokens
    }

}
```

Comment: :( Can you PLS elaborate more "logic to revoke tokens" with means of `LogoutSuccessHandler`?

Comment: What are you using for TokenStore?

Comment: I am using `JdbcTokenStore`.

Comment: Not sure about your configuration for Authorisation server, you will need to add DefaultTokenServices bean and then invoke the revokeToken() method from the logout success hander, this might help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992201/how-to-revoke-auth-token-in-spring-security

Comment: The `DefaultTokenServices.revokeToken()` pointed me right direction. Missing key to the question was `OAuth2AccessToken.getRefreshToken()` method. With that I can find and revoke refresh token.